# Center an image vertically between the website header and bottom of window

Tags: html, css

I am currently centring an image horizontally and vertically using:

```
.centeredImage
    {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    }

  .centeredImage img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

html:

```
<body>

    <p class="centeredImage"><img id ="img" src="smallslide1.png"></p>

</body>
```

This has been working fine however I have now added a header:

```
#header {
   background: #e9e6e6; /* Here set your colour */
   height: 55px;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
/* box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;*/
}
```

If I resize the window or the window isn't set at the perfect size this centered image will overlap the header. What I really want is it to be centered vertically between the bottom of the header and the bottom of the window. I tried adjusting top/bottom on the centered img but didn't have any luck. Could someone give me some pointers on how to go about this please?

Comment: A fiddle would be nice... But from what I understood maybe you should increase the top value of .centeredImage img to 55px?

Comment: You may want to look into the use of display:table-cell and display:table for vertical alignment. Often one of the easiest ways to achieve it.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/7avr1ubc/ Callum's solution would work too

Comment: @Moogs your fiddle works for keeping the image away from the header but if I drag the window down it remains in the same place and doesn't centre from the bottom of the header to the bottom of the window...

Comment: @KexAri how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/7avr1ubc/10/

Comment: @Moogs works for the square but with a 310*675 tall image I am using still overlap

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Fq8Q9g7o25 I have setup a fiddle. I have a logo in the bottom right corner that stays there regardless of the window size. I have my phone image centered in the screen but I don't want it to overlap the header for small windows.

Comment: @Pi_isnt_42 sfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Fq8Q9g7o25

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like following:

```css
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.centeredImage
    {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    }

  .centeredImage img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 55px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
#header {
   background: #e9e6e6; /* Here set your colour */
   height: 55px;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
    top:0;
   position: absolute;
/* box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div> 
<p class="centeredImage"><img id ="img" src="smallslide1.png"></p>
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rmg0d8r4/) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add div tag before and use some styles example

```
<body>
 <div>
 <p><img src="sample.png" alt="test"></p>
 </div>
</body>
```

## Style

```
div{display: inline-table;text-align: center}
div p{display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;}
```

And use padding-top: {header height should be placed here}px

for example if header height is 50px;

```
div{padding-top: 50px}
```

Comment: tried this couldn't get it working: I setup a fiddle jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Fq8Q9g7o25